# confused about len() in IPython notebook? what is the counting rule?

Tags: python

I am confused about the len() in IPython notebook.

The following is part of a text file "hamlet.txt"

```
XXXX
HAMLET, PRINCE OF DENMARK

by William Shakespeare




PERSONS REPRESENTED.

......
```

Case 1:
When copy this text file from the lab repository of CS109,  I use the code:

```
test_hamlet = open("hamlet.txt")
test_length = [len(line) for line in test_hamlet]
print test_length
```

the output should be a list

```
[9, 27, 2, 24, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, ......]
```

However, the first line just has 4 letters.

Case 2:
I did not neither put a letter into the text file nor take any letter from the text file. The only thing I did just save this file. For example, I add a letter Y after XXXXY and then take if off and save.

```
XXXX
HAMLET, PRINCE OF DENMARK

by William Shakespeare




PERSONS REPRESENTED.

......
```

This time I use the same code:

```
test_hamlet = open("hamlet.txt")
test_length = [len(line) for line in test_hamlet]
print test_length
```

However, the output is as follows:

```
[6, 27, 2, 24, 2, 2, 2, 2, 22, ......]
```

Case N:
Use the same text file. The only difference is changing something and recovering the change and saving the text file.

Use the same code. The output is different. This really confuses me a lot.

What is the real counting rule for this len() function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you convert the lines into lists and print those out so you can see the full content including newlines and tabs. See `list(line)`

Comment: I'd be interested in what the first few elements of `[repr(line) for line in test_hamlet]` are if you can show it...

Comment: I don't know, but maybe the encoding? For example DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending and Unix uses just line feed ("\n")

Comment: Yes, you are right this is a problem related to the encoding. checking the full content with list(line) or [repr(line) for line in test_hamlet ] both work well. Thanks, guys.